# OpenFaas - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: kubernetes-helm, openfaas

I have deployed openfaas through helm using the following command

`helm upgrade openfaas --install openfaas/opehelmnfaas --namespace default --set functionNamespace=default --set generateBasicAuth=true`

Everything is working properly but when I attempt a post request with data greater than ~1,000 KB I am getting the following response

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>

<body>
 <center>
  <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
 </center>
 <hr>
 <center>openresty/1.15.8.1</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way I can control the request entity size threshold when installing through helm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies! The threshold was actually being enforced on an external Ingress, which can easily be configured using annotations in its yaml file

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    version: {{ .Chart.Version }}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: {{ .Values.size }}
spec:
...`